# How to add a database.mwb to my server user schema

Tags: php, mysql-workbench

I'm new with mySQL workbench.

my friend has sent me his database in form of 'database.mwb'
and I'm trying to add his database to my schema for my server.

my code was like this:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "******", "chefDatabase");
$message = $con->query("SELECT PreferredContactMethod FROM Chef")->fetch_object()->message;
$con->close();
echo "$message <br/>";
echo "Hello From Sites Folder!";
phpinfo();
?>
```

I could not reach the tables from my code. can you help?

Comment: Start by moving `$con->close();` after you've tried to echo `$message`. You've closed it (the connection) too soon.

Comment: thank you very much, I did move it. but still, I was not able to add the tables my friend created to my database as I get the error: Table 'chefDatabase.chef' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

it worked with me like this:
from database I chose reverse engineer and walked through it. I was given the ability to select the schema to reverse engineer (the one I wand to add my tables to).

Comment: Forward engineer*